# ASP.Net Menu Not Working In Edge

Tags: asp.net, redirect, microsoft-edge

My company has a website written in ASP.Net 4. On the site master page there is a navigation menu with the following markup:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" 
            CssClass="menu" EnableViewState="False" 
                                    IncludeStyleBlock="False" 
                                    onmenuitemclick="Menu1_MenuItemClick" 
            BackColor="#ECFFF5" Font-Size="Larger" >
            <DynamicSelectedStyle ForeColor="#0000FF" />
            <StaticSelectedStyle Font-Underline="true" />
                <Items>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="General Information" Value="~/Default.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Value="~/LandDetail.aspx" Text="Land Detail"/>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Buildings Detail" Value="~/Buildings.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Value History" Value="~/ValueHistory.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem Text="Sales History" Value="~/SalesHistory.aspx"></asp:MenuItem>
                </Items>
</asp:Menu>
```

The function Menu1_MenuItemClick redirects to the appropriate page based on the value (some menu items link to external pages, but I haven't included the complete markup).

This works in every browser I've tested on except Edge. After replacing the contents of Menu1_MenuItemClick with `Response.Write("<script>console.log('In click event')</script>")`, I checked the log output on all my test browsers. Each one would log the message except Edge, which leads me to believe that for some reason, the click event is not firing in Edge.

Seems like this is a bug in Edge. Has anyone else encountered this? If so, were you able to fix it?

**Edit**
Here is the html and javascript generated in Edge. I believe this is all the relevant portions, but if there's anything else I should include, let me know.

HTML:

```
<a href="#Menu1_SkipLink">
  <img alt="Skip Navigation Links" src="/WebResource.axd?d=3zekzOm7wdY2v6Fqj9tMppVjePvTb6jHiJpivJ5DBS4_4BhMD9MhlesmVZZYvoXaQDeTYipLC7c2b27tAT6ZyWbpl5iXmJF3JNrd6yUyViI1&amp;t=636125516399126630" width="0" height="0" style="border-width:0px;" />
</a>
<div class="menu" id="Menu1">
  <ul class="level1">
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/Default.aspx&#39;)">General Information</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/LandDetail.aspx&#39;)">Land Detail</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/Buildings.aspx&#39;)">Buildings Detail</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/ValueHistory.aspx&#39;)">Value History</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/SalesHistory.aspx&#39;)">Sales History</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/TaxChargesPayments2.aspx&#39;)">Tax Charges and Payments</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;TaxRates&#39;)">Current Tax Rates</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/WhereTaxesGo.aspx&#39;)">Where Your Taxes Go</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/TaxEstimator.aspx&#39;)">Tax Estimator</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;Map&#39;)">Map</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;~/Sketch.aspx&#39;)">Sketch</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;PRC&#39;)">Property Record Card</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;Photo&#39;)">Photo Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;Recorder&#39;)">Deed Record</a></li>
    <li><a class="level1" href="#" onclick="__doPostBack(&#39;ctl00$Menu1&#39;,&#39;NewSearch&#39;)">New Search</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
    if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
        theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
        theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
        theForm.submit();
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be more helpful to post the rendered HTML, CSS and JS output which result from this asp code, since that's what Edge will be interacting with. Did you check your console for any errors at the moment you clicked the button? It should cause a full postback - does that not occur?

Comment: @ADyson, see my edited question

Comment: As I already mentioned, what about any errors/problems at the moment you click on any of the links? Watch your network tab. Does it post back, or not?

Comment: I tried watching the network tab in Firefox and Edge. In Firefox, there's a postback followed by a GET request to the desired page. Edge does the postback, but the subsequent GET request is for the page I'm already on rather than the new page. Also of note, Edge lists the protocol and status of each GET/POST request. For each request, it lists the protocol as HTTP and the status as 200 (OK), but the postback protocol and status are both "Pending". Maybe the postback is hanging? There are no errors being displayed in the console.

Comment: Strange. What happens in your server-side debugger during this? Does it hit the C# event handler method? P.S. Unless you do something interesting/useful in the server event for this (do you??), then you could just replace the `<asp:Menu` guff with the same `<ul>` etc written by hand, and containing normal hyperlinks that any browser can definitely process.

Comment: I decided to take your suggestion and just get rid of th `<asp:Menu>`. I think once upon a time it had some fancy functionality that had to be done on the server, but now it's just a nav menu. Once I replaced it with plain old html markup, all my problems went away. Thanks!